# IBM MQ C# Windows personal certificate for TLS connection

Tags: c#, ssl, ibm-mq

I'm looking for an example to connect a non-managed C# application to IBM MQ using TLS channel (SVRCONN) connections with Windows "personal certificate". The certificate can be seen using certmgr.msc under "Certificated - current user" -> Personal -> Certificates.

I've found one example on how to access the certificate.

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
```

But looking at IBM's documentation on SSL/TLS channel connections I can't quite figure out how the X509Store can be passed to the channel connection or MQEnvironment structure:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029670_.htm

Comment: It's looking for a physical file when you set MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository?

Comment: yes, standard is a key file called "key.kdb". Which however probably just contains the same as in the X509Store...

Comment: You can not use the windows personal certificate with unmanaged .NET.  If you use Manged .NET you may be able to.  Unmanaged .net needs to be pointed specifically to a CMS (.kdb) file.